# Simple Plugin with MEF .How Can I load plugin using a config File

Tags: mef

I am writing a small plugin architecture and I have decided to use MEF 
I have been told that we must use a config file.

Is there any example out there that that uses Mef and a config file?

All I need is how to set up mef in a config file is this possible? This is a small noddy example I have built to test it I am missing the loadPlugin function and config file Can you help

Noddy example

```
                       //MyCompany.Payment.Contracts.dll

        public interface IPayment
        {
            bool Pay();
        }
        //MyCompany.Payment.ServiceProviderOne.dll
          [Export(typeof(IPayment))]
        public class ServiceProviderOne:IPayment
        {
            public bool Pay(return true);
        }
        //MyCompany.Payment.ServiceProviderTwo.dll
          [Export(typeof(IPayment))]
        public class ServiceProviderTwo:IPayment
        {
            ?public bool Pay(return true);
        }

        //Main Console.Applicaiton
        class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    HelperPlugin helperPlugin =new HelperPlugin();
                    List<IPayment> myLoadedPayments= helperPlugin.GetPlugins();

                    //blahhh conti
                }
            }

            public cass HelperPlugin
            {
                [ImportMany(typeof(IPayment))]
                public List<IPayment>Payments { get; set; }

                public List<IPayment>GetPlugins()
                {
                    Payments=new List<IPayment>();
                    LoadPlugins();

                    return Payments;
                }

                private void LoadPlugins()
                {
                 ???
                }
            }
```

Config File What does it look like?

Thanks for any suggestions or code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on a similar issue right now and my approach is this:

- I'm planning to have a config file that defines how my `CompositionContainer` will be configured
- My config should contain a list of directories for the container to scan (by using a `DirectoryCatalog` for each directory specified)
- and my config should also support a list of assemblies that might be stored elsewhere, and that would be included by having several `AssemblyCatalog` used for that purpose

So basically, I'm trying to configure the individual catalogs that make up my `AggregateCatalog` which the composition container will use to find the parts. Not there yet, unfortunately - so this is just in my head for now - no code just yet.

Answer (score 1):

What I did in a recent project was to include a Name property in the interface. All the extensions I wanted to be accessible got loaded, then a config file setting listed the ones by Name that I wanted to use. I used a loop to inspect the extensions that were loaded and, if they were named in the setting, I added them to an internal list.

My requirement was to have a specific order that extensions were used, so this solution worked for me.

I could have included metadata in the assemblies to accomplish the same thing, but wanted the information more visible and part of the contract.